# Is it possible to use drawable+color as background?

Tags: android

I have an opaque pattern (10% opacity) and I need to combine it with some color.

Is it possible to set background color to image?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure. Just use a LayerListDrawable.

Something like:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FF00ffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
         <bitmap 
             android:src="@drawable/your_tiled_drawable"
             android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Save that in your `res/drawables` directory, and use it as your background.

Sadly, if your application is more complicated, sometimes the tileMode will get unset for no apparent reason. If you run in to that, you'll have to re-add the tile mode in Java.

I usually still set it in xml, and then do something like:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
LayerDrawable lld = (LayerDrawable) v.getBackground();
BitmapDrawable tiled = (BitmapDrawable) lld.getDrawable(1);
tiled.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Comment: Awesome, thats what i was looking for.

Comment: @ABentSpoon, exactly what I'm looking for but the image gets stretched. How do I keep the aspect ratio of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You could use `ImageView`. Set its background color and  set the semi-transparent image as its source.

If you want to do this to a layout, then extend that layout and in overridden onDraw(), draw the background color and blend with the semi-transparent image

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
```